# Am I need to delete the image which is stored at path_provider.getTemporaryDirectory() as i am using it as temporary place holder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a flutter plugin named `path_provider`. I have to store image file at `path_provider.getTemporaryDirectory()`. Is the image stored here is deleted automatically or I have to do it explicitly.

Comment: If you know any way of cleaning this temporary directory within program then please provide the solution to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

from the documentation of `path_provider`

> Files in this directory may be cleared at any time. This does *not* return
> a new temporary directory. Instead, the caller is responsible for creating
> (and cleaning up) files or directories within this directory. This
> directory is scoped to the calling application.

So you are responsible for cleaning up, which means it is not automatically cleared, but it may be cleared any time

**Edit**

You can clear the temporary the directory as follows:

```
import 'dart:io';
....
Directory dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
dir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
dir.create(); // This will create the temporary directory again. So temporary files will only be deleted
```

Comment: If you know any way of cleaning this temporary directory within program then please provide the solution to me. Thank you.

Comment: This will also delete the director which can lead to bad things...

Answer (score 0):

To keep things safe, I store all the file paths in list with flutter_secure_storage, then when I launch the app I browse all the file paths, check if file still exists (can be previously deleted by system) and delete it. Finally, I clear the list from flutter_secure_storage for next time.

AppSecureStorage.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class AppSecureStorage {
  static const _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  static const TEMP_FILES_PATH = 'temp-files-path';

  static Future<String?> get(String key) async {
    return await _storage.read(key: key);
  }

  static Future<void> set(String key, String? value) async {
    if (value == null) {
      await _storage.delete(key: key);
    } else {
      await _storage.write(
        key: key,
        value: value,
      );
    }
  }

  static Future<List<String>> getTempFilesPath() async {
    final tempFilesPathValue = await get(
      AppSecureStorage.TEMP_FILES_PATH,
    );

    List<String> tempFilesPathStrList = [];

    if (tempFilesPathValue != null) {
      List<dynamic> tempFilesPathDynamicList = jsonDecode(tempFilesPathValue);
      for (var element in tempFilesPathDynamicList) {
        tempFilesPathStrList.add(element.toString());
      }
    }

    return tempFilesPathStrList;
  }

  static Future<void> addTempFile(String filePath) async {
    final tempFilesPath = await AppSecureStorage.getTempFilesPath();
    tempFilesPath.add(filePath);

    AppSecureStorage.set(
      AppSecureStorage.TEMP_FILES_PATH,
      jsonEncode(tempFilesPath),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
void _handleTempFiles() async {
    List<String> tempFilesPath = await AppSecureStorage.getTempFilesPath();

    for (var element in tempFilesPath) {
      final file = File(element);
      // check if still exist : tmp file can be deleted by system
      if (await file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
      }
    }

    AppSecureStorage.set(AppSecureStorage.TEMP_FILES_PATH, jsonEncode([]));
  }
```

Comment: Hi mate, can you share the code please?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the answers, if you use the `file_picker` package, you can call the method `clearTemporaryFiles`.

```
await FilePicker.platform.clearTemporaryFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<File> createTempFile(Uint8List uint8List) async {
// Create a temporary directory
Directory tempDir = await Directory.systemTemp.createTemp();

// Create a temporary file
File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/temp_image.png');

// Write the image bytes to the file
await tempFile.writeAsBytes(uint8List);

return tempFile;
```

}

//Whenever this function called again or app-restart this tempDir will be auto-cleared